# How to merge reports in v5 of extent reports?

Tags: report, reporting, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I have been using version 3 of Extent Reports for a while now. Everything works great but I want to use version 5 now since it's better and it has more functionality.

I know that in version 3 you can use `htmlReporter.setAppendExisting(true);` to append test results to the report but how do you do it in v5?

I have looked through their documentation and I found this piece of code that is apparently supposed to work but I am getting a weird error.

This is the code:

```
spark = new ExtentSparkReporter (System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/reporti/TestExtentReport.html");

JsonFormatter json = new JsonFormatter("extent.json");
        
extent = new ExtentReports();
        
extent.createDomainFromJsonArchive("extent.json");
        
extent.attachReporter(spark,json);
        
logger = extent.createTest("Sklepanje");`
```

When I run this I am getting this error after the test is complete:

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest iTriglavTesti.TestExtent.endReport
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private java.lang.String java.lang.Throwable.detailMessage accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @2cb4c3ab
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:153)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:416)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldAdapter(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:135)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:105)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:104)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:416)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldAdapter(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:135)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:105)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:104)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:416)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:53)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:416)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldAdapter(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:135)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:105)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:104)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:416)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:55)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:661)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:640)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:615)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.JsonFormatter.flush(JsonFormatter.java:57)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.JsonFormatter.access$000(JsonFormatter.java:17)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.JsonFormatter$1.onNext(JsonFormatter.java:37)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.JsonFormatter$1.onNext(JsonFormatter.java:30)
    at io.reactivex.rxjava3.subjects.PublishSubject$PublishDisposable.onNext(PublishSubject.java:310)
    at io.reactivex.rxjava3.subjects.PublishSubject.onNext(PublishSubject.java:226)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.ReactiveSubject.onFlush(ReactiveSubject.java:83)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.AbstractProcessor.onFlush(AbstractProcessor.java:85)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports.flush(ExtentReports.java:279)
    at iTriglavTesti.TestExtent.endReport(TestExtent.java:433)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:69)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:361)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:296)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.invokeTestConfigurations(TestRunner.java:644)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.afterRun(TestRunner.java:914)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:605)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:437)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:431)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:391)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:330)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1256)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1176)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1099)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1067)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

I tried commenting out `extent.createDomainFromJsonArchive("extent.json");` first and nothing changes I am still getting same error, but after I commented out `JsonFormatter json = new JsonFormatter("extent.json");` the problem went away so I'm guessing there's something wrong here?

If anyone knows what's wrong or has any idea of what might be wrong please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

In Extent 5 you can merge multiple HTML reports if you have the .json file generated by extent Report , we can use those to create a single html report with all merged results

#1 First we create a common output Folder for extent json files so that we can merge them all from a common folder
#2 Them we generate two sample html Reports with there extent json files which are then written to common json folder

```
JsonFormatter json2 = new JsonFormatter(opFolder + "/Report2.json");
```

#3 Then we Create a Third extent Report , Take all the generated json files from folder and add their data into this and it will create a merged Report

```
 extentMerged.createDomainFromJsonArchive(jsonFile.getPath());
```

Full Code

```
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.JsonFormatter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class TestBase {

    public static void main(String... a) throws IOException {

        //Creating a Directory for Extent Json Output and create it if doesn't exist
        File file = new File("ExtentJson");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }
        String opFolder = file.getPath();

        //Creating individual Report Number 1
        ExtentSparkReporter spark = new ExtentSparkReporter("Report1.html");
        JsonFormatter json = new JsonFormatter(opFolder + "/Report1.json");
        ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.createTest("test1").assignCategory("cat").pass("Step 1 from test 1")
            .fail("step 2 from test 1");
        extent.attachReporter(json, spark);
        extent.flush();

        //Creating individual Report Number 2
        ExtentSparkReporter spark2 = new ExtentSparkReporter("Report2.html");
        JsonFormatter json2 = new JsonFormatter(opFolder + "/Report2.json");
        ExtentReports extent2 = new ExtentReports();
        extent2.createTest("test2").assignCategory("cat").pass("Step 1 from test 2")
            .fail("step 2 from test 2");
        extent2.attachReporter(json2, spark2);
        extent2.flush();

        ExtentSparkReporter mergedSpark = new ExtentSparkReporter("spark.html");
        ExtentReports extentMerged = new ExtentReports();

        //Replace below logic to get all the .json files generated by extent in opFolder
        File jsonOPDirectory = new File("ExtentJson");
        if (jsonOPDirectory.exists()) {
            Arrays.stream(jsonOPDirectory.listFiles()).forEach(jsonFile -> {

                try {
                    extentMerged.createDomainFromJsonArchive(jsonFile.getPath());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }

        extentMerged.attachReporter(mergedSpark);
        extentMerged.flush();
    }

}
```

Reference
[Combine Multiple Reports](https://www.extentreports.com/docs/versions/5/java/index.html#combine-multiple-reports)

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue after upgrading from jdk11 to jdk17. After asking on extent-framework github, it was determined that it's a bug, currently in queue to be resolved. If that may be connected to your issue, you can follow it [here](https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-java/issues/331#issuecomment-1720365727).

Edited on 22/09/2023 : fix to that issue got introduced in ver. 5.1.1